# Why does SSH show protocol as tcp6 *and* tcp in netstat?

Tags: ssh, ipv6, netstat, protocols

```
$ netstat -nat
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Why are there two records of port 22 (`:::22` and `0.0.0.0:22`) and why does one use protocol as `tcp` and the other as `tcp6`

This is on Ubuntu 12.04.4

Comment: Well, because SSH is listening on the wildcard addresses of both IPv4 and IPv6 so you could reach your SSH daemon through both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `sshd` uses ipv4 and ipv6.  You can configure the protocol sshd uses through the `AddressFamily` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

For ipv4 & ipv6 (default)

```
AddressFamily any
```

For ipv4 only

```
AddressFamily inet
```

For ipv6 only

```
AddressFamily inet6
```

After you make any changes to `sshd_config` restart `sshd` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Above answer is correct, and answer below, containing words: "even if you completely disable IPv6" sheds not config advice, but info why tools like netstat show IPv6 (or IPv4) present, although you disabled one of IP protocols on your network device(s).

You can disable IPv6 on network interface, but you will see it present in tools like netstat if you configure some service to listen on it.
You need to disable IPv6 BOTH in configuration of your services and via kernel parameters (e.g. using sysctl command) to eliminate IPv6 fully from your system.
Seems little ambiguous, but it is so.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's slightly more interesting

Basically, even if you completely disable IPv6, some sockets will get identified as "TCP6/UDP6" due to curious kernel reasons.

I noticed it after I ran netstat on an android phone that was connected to a 3G network without an inking of IPv6 support (disabled in APN settings and explicitly not supported by carrier)

After I saw that TCP6 connections of WhatsApp somehow persist, I started researching and found this link:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/04/note-netstat/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to bind only on `::` and talk both IPv4 and IPv6. I have wondered why some applications, including openssh, do not take advantage of this.

This [section about IPv6 in the FreeBSD developers' handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/ipv6.html#ipv6-wildcard-socket) has some interesting commentary that may be relevant:

> It looks that RFC2553 talks too little on wildcard bind issue,
>   especially on the port space issue, failure mode and relationship
>   between AF_INET/INET6 wildcard bind. There can be several separate
>   interpretation for this RFC which conform to it but behaves
>   differently. So, to implement portable application you should assume
>   nothing about the behavior in the kernel. Using getaddrinfo(3) is the
>   safest way. Port number space and wildcard bind issues were discussed
>   in detail on ipv6imp mailing list, in mid March 1999 and it looks that
>   there is no concrete consensus (means, up to implementers). You may
>   want to check the mailing list archives.

We may also speculate that this default behavior was defined when a significant number of systems did not have IPv6 support.